# twitter bootstrap modal not loading

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is he code that i basically copied from the twitter bootstrap page. However, it isnt loading at all! All my files are correct but the modal is still not showing up. Please help me.

```
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/autoresize_textbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/submit_validate.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>
</head> 

<body> 


<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in Javascript Error console ??

Comment: This is not related to php. Please remove php tag.

Comment: Note: there's no need to include both `bootstrap.js` *and* `bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: upon all your scripts, is it just the `modal` that isn't working?

Comment: please paste all your js file in the bottom of html page, and include dependent js file first. eg load jquery first etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>` first before including bootstrap js.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> //Optional
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/autoresize_textbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/submit_validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: does the order really matter?

Comment: HEY it worked! Thanks so much! Never knew order in which you access the files mattered.

Comment: Happy to know! If it solves your problem, then don't forget to accept the answer.